# How to find all where query in Symfony 3 Doctrine

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have table named `post` and column `string` named `status` with data `published` or `pending`. Now I want to fetch all rows from this table with `EntityRepository` class custom method or just modify existing method.

I have tried this:

```
public function queryLatestPublished()
{
  return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p
            FROM AppBundle:Post
            WHERE p.staus == :st
            ORDER BY p.created DESC
        ')
        ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime())
        ->setParameter('st', 'published')
    ;
}
```

but the query does not return anything.

Comment: What is the problem with your try (except that you have more parameters set than used in the query)?

Comment: Is it symfony2 or symfony3? Your headline and tag don't match.

Comment: This code returns `Query` object. Did you tried to execute the query? Also in SQL and DQL the equality operator is `=` not `==`.

Comment: yes i missed the execute part, thanks i will try.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors/problems in your code

- number of parameters provided does not match number of expected
- you don't call getResult (or any other execute like method) so you actually return Query object
- I would change naming of method because it's misleading

also I would change

- you probably want to limit somehow number of results
- using `select` and `from` when working with querybuilder can be omitted if you are inside entity repository (in this case Post)

My proposition:

```
/**
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 *
 * @return Post[]
 */
public function findNewestPublished($limit = 10, $offset = 0)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.status = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'published')
        ->addOrderBy('p.createdAt', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getResult();
}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $sql = "SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Post WHERE p.staus = ?1 ORDER BY p.created DESC'";
 $query = $em->createQuery($sql);
 $query->setParameter(1, 'published');
 $result = $query->getResult();
```

for more info see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples